# how to ignore factors or levels while using summary function in R

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset which has a column with only 2 possible values i.e. 0 and 1. I applied `as.factor()` to this column and it created two levels for me.

```
dr$col <- as.factor(dr$col)
```

Now when I do `summary(dataset)` it gives me occurrences of those values instead of mean/max/min etc. values.

```
summary(dr)

col
0:12
1:34
```

How can I advice summary function to ignore the factors for that column and calculate aggregate values like it does for other numeric columns.

Comment: `summary(unclass(x))` ?

Comment: I think unclassing will give you the index integers rather than the 0:1 values. Should be the usual `as.numeric(as.character())`-approach.

Comment: Cheshh, do you want to have factors, or numeric values? You changed the original variable to a factor, why the generic function `summary` uses it's method for factors. If you don't want this, why do you apply `as.factor`? If you want to have a boolean variable (e.g. for modeling) use `as.logical` and for your summary `as.numeric`. Otherwise @BondedDust gave the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following

```
  >> vec=c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
  >> vecf=as.factor(vec)
```

Then the following will give you the desired results

```
  >> summary(as.numeric(as.character(vecf)))
```

Comment: as.numeric(as.character()) works. Thanks BondedDust and Ala and all who tried it for me......